# Discord.JS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => { //message.guild.channels.find('name', 'logs')
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    //var channel = client.channels.cache.get("701096779990695977")
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('TEST')
        .addField('TESTOĞLU', member.nickname)
        .setImage(member.user.avatarURL)
    //channel.send(embed);
    //member.guild.channels.find('whitelist-onay', 'logs').send({embed});
    //message.channel.send(embed);
    client.channels.cache.get('701096779990695977').send("embed");
})
```

Please help me ı want to send welcome message in a channel (discord)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah ı did. Here is code.

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => { //message.guild.channels.find('name', 'logs')
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'whitelist-onay')
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('TEST')
        .addField('TESTOĞLU', member.nickname)
        .setImage(member.user.avatarURL)
    //channel.send(embed);
    if (!channel) return;
    //member.guild.channels.find('whitelist-onay', 'logs').send({embed});
    //message.channel.send(embed);
    channel.send(embed);
})
```